# Find overlapping Regexp matches

Tags: ruby, regex, overlap

I want to find all matches within a given string including overlapping matches. How could I achieve it?

```
# Example
"a-b-c-d".???(/\w-\w/)  # => ["a-b", "b-c", "c-d"] expected

# Solution without overlapped results
"a-b-c-d".scan(/\w-\w/) # => ["a-b", "c-d"], but "b-c" is missing
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use capturing inside a positive lookahead:

```
"a-b-c-d".scan(/(?=(\w-\w))/).flatten
 # => ["a-b", "b-c", "c-d"]
```

See [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/vedrYG)

Comment: Works perfectly, also with complex patterns. `"abaca".scan(/(?=(\w)(?:(?!\1)(\w))\1)/)  #=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"]]`.

Comment: ...or positive lookbehind: `"a-b-c-d".scan(/(?<=(\w-\w))/).flatten`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a non-regex solution:

```
"a-b-c-d".delete('-').each_char.each_cons(2).map { |s| s.join('-') }
  #=> ["a-b", "b-c", "c-d"]
```

or

```
"a-b-c-d".each_char.each_cons(3).select.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }.map(&:join)
  #=> ["a-b", "b-c", "c-d"]
```

or

```
enum = "a-b-c-d".each_char
a = []
loop do
  a << "%s%s%s" % [enum.next, enum.next, enum.peek]
end
a #=> ["a-b", "b-c", "c-d"]
```

Comment: Your last technique is very very neat.

Comment: Nice answer, but I was explicitly asking for a regexp. The pattern above was just the simplest one I found to explain my problem. The pattern I actually use, is `(\w)(?:(?!\1)(\w))\1`.