# regex match longest substring with equal first and last char

Tags: regex, ruby

```
/(\w)(\w*)\1/
```

For this string:"mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv" I match "txrvxjnwksqhxuxt" (using Ruby), but not the even longer valid substring "tdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxt".

Comment: `/(\w)(\w*)\1/.match("mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv")` only matches `gntdyg`. Can you show how you got your longer match?

Comment: The first match `gntdyg` overlaps the beginning of your desired match, so you'll need a different approach - *capture* each possible match in a lookahead instead of matching normally.

Comment: [Find overlapping Regexp matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028602/find-overlapping-regexp-matches) is a start. There is no solution that could help with a regex containing two capturing groups but should provide some ideas on how to solve the current problem. Also, notice that regex itself cannot find longest or shortest matches, it just matches or not starting with the leftmost match (since the regex engine parses the string from left to right). Hence, you cannot expect it to parse all through a string and find your expected longest substring (it is not the first match).

Comment: `'mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv'.scan(/(?=((\w).*(\2)))/).map(&:first).sort_by(&:size).last #=> "tdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxt"`

Comment: Or, [`'mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv'.scan(/(?=((\w)\w*\2))/).map(&:first).max_by(&:length)`](https://ideone.com/o3ROyj).

Comment: @Schwern like this "mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv".scan(/(\w)(\w*)\1/)

Answer (score 0):

For a given string, here are two ways to find the longest substring that begins and ends with the same character.

Suppose

```
str = "mgntdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxtrv"
```

**Use a regular expression**

```
r = /(.)(?=(.*\1))/
str.gsub(r).map { $1 + $2 }.max_by(&:length)
  #=> "tdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxt".
```

When, as here, the regular expression contains capture groups, it may be more convenient to use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) without a second argument or block (in which case it returns an enumerator, which can be chained) than [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) (" If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.") Here `gsub` performs no substitutions; it merely generates matches of the regular expression.

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*.

```
r = /
    (.)       # match any char and save to capture group 1
    (?=       # begin a positive lookahead
      (.*\1)  # match >= 0 characters followed by the contents of capture group 1 
    )         # end the postive lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The following intermediate calculation is performed:

```
str.gsub(r).map { $1 + $2 }
  #=> ["gntdyg", "ntdygtxrvxjn", "tdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxt", "txrvxjnwksqhxuxt",
  #    "xrvxjnwksqhxux", "rvxjnwksqhxuxtr", "vxjnwksqhxuxtrv", "xjnwksqhxux",
  #    "xux"]
```

Notice that this does not enumerate all substrings beginning and ending with the same character (because `.*` is greedy). It does not generate, for example, the substring `"xrvx"`.

**Do not use a regular expression**

```
v = str.each_char.with_index.with_object({}) do |(c,i),h|
  if h.key?(c)
    h[c][:size] = i - h[c][:start] + 1
  else
    h[c] = { start: i, size: 1 }
  end
end.max_by { |_,h| h[:size] }.last
str[v[:start], v[:size]]
  #=> "tdygtxrvxjnwksqhxuxt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailled explanation, this use of gsub and the max_by function were completely new to me.